# Assign a Variable in If statement [C++]

Tags: c++, scope

I am trying to assign a variable if one variable equals another value.  Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a = 5;
   int b;

   cout << "A is this value (before if):  " << a << endl;
   cout << "B is this value (before if):  " << b << endl;


   if (a==5)
   {
       cout << "A equals five" << endl;
       int b = 6;
       cout << "B is this value (if stmt):  " << b << endl;
   }

cout << "B is this value (outside):  " << b << endl;

   return 0;

}
```

It outputs the following:

```
A is this value (before if):  5
B is this value (before if):  0
A equals five
B is this value (if stmt):  6
B is this value (outside):  0
```

Why does variable "b" not stay assigned as 6 once it leaves the if statement?  And is there a better way to assign it? In my actual code I have five variables I compare to a.

Comment: remove `int` from `int b = 6;` - then learn about [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Comment: Different `b`. The inner scope `b` hides the first by name. And fyi this invokes undefined behavior regardless, as the outer `b` is never assigned a value before evaluation during your output insertions.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2):

You declared a new variable inside the `if` block. Replace the variable declaration with an assignment.

Also, you should initialize the original `b` variable. Printing its value without initializing it results in undefined behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a = 5;
   int b = 0;

   cout << "A is this value (before if):  " << a << endl;
   cout << "B is this value (before if):  " << b << endl;

   if (a==5)
   {
       cout << "A equals five" << endl;
       b = 6;
       cout << "B is this value (if stmt):  " << b << endl;
   }

   cout << "B is this value (outside):  " << b << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `int b = 6;` introduces a new variable `b` that's initialized to 6. It doesn't set 6 to the `b` of the outer scope. To do that, you should remove the type specifier:

```
b = 6;
```

Right now because `b` is never initialized you have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`int b = 6` inside of the *if* block is bringing a scope problem, the ***new variable*** is shadowing the variable you declared in main function

you need to do:

```
  if (a==5)
   {
       cout << "A equals five" << endl;
       b = 6;
       cout << "B is this value (if stmt):  " << b << endl;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
   int a = 5;
   int b; // this instance of b has scope over the entire main() function

   cout << "A is this value (before if):  " << a << endl;
   cout << "B is this value (before if):  " << b << endl;


   if (a==5)
   {
       cout << "A equals five" << endl;
       int b = 6; // this instance of b only exists inside this if statement. As soon as the program leaves this if, this instance of b stops existing
       cout << "B is this value (if stmt):  " << b << endl;
   }

cout << "B is this value (outside):  " << b << endl;

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: this looks like a code only answer. Consider to add some text, as the comments can be overlooked easily